# Why foldr (\ x xs -> x : x : xs) [] wont work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to see the difference in these 2 functions:

```
dupli = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ [x,x]) []
dupli = foldr (\ x xs -> x : x : xs) []
```

I know the difference between foldl and foldr but for the examples I've seen on how it works, using `(+)`, it looks the same except for the method of summing.

Why

```
dupli = foldr (\acc x -> acc ++ [x,x]) []
```

gives

```
/workspaces/hask_exercises/exercises/src/Lib.hs:142:27: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a]
        Actual type: [[a]]
    * In the expression: acc ++ [x, x]
      In the first argument of `foldr', namely
        `(\ acc x -> acc ++ [x, x])'
      In the expression: foldr (\ acc x -> acc ++ [x, x]) []
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:142:22)
        acc :: [[a]] (bound at src/Lib.hs:142:18)
        dupli' :: t [[a]] -> [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:142:1)
    |
142 | dupli' = foldr (\acc x -> acc ++ [x,x]) []
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the type signatures. (Note: I'm specializing both of these to `[]` rather than a general `Foldable` for simplicity here)

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So in `foldl`, the "accumulator argument" is the first argument to the folding function, whereas in `foldr`, it's the second.

You mention `(+)`. `(+)` is a function where the left-hand and right-hand arguments have the same type, so you wouldn't notice the difference. Specifically,

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

But `(:)` is different.

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Since your initial accumulator is, in both cases, `[]`, you can use `(:)` in the `foldr` case since the accumulator type `[a]` is the second argument, but in the `foldl` case we're required to do some tricks with `++`.

Comment: …or we can also use `:` with `foldl` and `++` with `foldr`, but it'll have different functionality: `revDupl = foldl (\xs x -> x : x : xs) []` and `revDupl = foldr (\x xs -> xs ++ [x,x]) []`